# How do I prevent Vim from unindenting empty lines?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, gvim

Vim keeps unindenting the lines I want to keep indented if I don't write anything on them... I'll give an example, where the | is the caret.

1. Caret is indented and I press enter

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")
       |
   ```
2. Caret is indented on the next line, and now I press the up arrow

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")

       |
   ```
3. Now the caret isn't indented anymore, what happened?

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")
   |
   ```

So how do I keep the indent?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883563/vim-keeps-unindenting

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages posting the same question on multiple sites. If you decide to post on a different site later, you're expected to delete the original question.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to keep trailing spaces?

Comment: Maybe you want to look into using `set virtualedit=all`? It doesn't do what you're asking for, but it is roughly similar (see the help page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the normal behavior of `'autoindent'` which the Python indent plugin uses. See `:help 'ai'`. You can watch what happens to the indent as you type by executing

```
:set list
```

There is no way that I know of to make Vim automatically preserve your indent in the case you describe. Setting the `I` flag of `'cpoptions'` doesn't help.

You can work around this problem by using the following mapping.

```
:inoremap <cr> <space><bs><cr>
```

That will cause Vim to leave an indentation of spaces when you type `Enter` on an empty line. I don't recommend doing that as it will leave your file cluttered with unnecessary spaces until you remove them with something like

```
:%s/\s\+$//
```

before saving the file, but you may find that less annoying than the normal indent behavior.

Answer (score 4):

To keep the indent ... write something on that line, before moving to other lines! Otherwise, since you are a good Vim user and stay mostly in normal mode (right?), when you have to write something on that line, just go there and press `S` - you'll find yourself at the correct indent level and ready to type. Vim does this to avoid useless ('trailing') tabs/spaces on empty lines.