# Pressing Enter removes indentation

Tags: indentation, cursor-movement, tab-characters, set

If I have a file `a.js` like this:

```
let a1 = [
];
```

and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the first line, a Tab is inserted. I do not want this, so I added a setting:

```
filetype indent off
```

but then if I have this:

```
let a1 = [
   10,
   20
];
```

I have to manually add tabs for each item. So I added another setting:

```
set autoindent
```

These two settings solve the existing problems, but introduce a new problem.

If I move the cursor to the start of one of the indented lines, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the indentation is removed. Can I change a setting to resolve this issue?

To respond to an answer, I can use these settings:

```
filetype indent off
set smartindent
```

and redo the second example. However, after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, if I then press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>, the indentation is removed, repeating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the methods in the question, I then tried this:

```
filetype indent off
function F_indent()
   return indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1))
endfunction
set indentexpr=F_indent()
```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#prevnonblank()

which passes the 2 tests in the question, but I noticed another problem. With
the second example, if I put the cursor at the beginning of the last line and
Press Enter, it inserts a Newline and a Tab. In addition, throughout these
tests I have also noticed that all the previous methods remove indentation on
empty lines:

[How do I prevent Vim from unindenting empty lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/unindenting-empty-lines)

So Ideally I wanted whatever I came up with to pass these tests:

1. whitespace removed only with backspace or delete
2. if cursor position greater than indent, match indent
3. if cursor position less or equal to indent, match position

To that end, I came up with this:

```
filetype indent off
function F_ind()
   let n_ind = indent(line('.'))
   let n_col = col('.') - 1
   if n_col > n_ind
      return "\n" . repeat("\t", n_ind / 3)
   else
      return "\n" . repeat("\t", n_col / 3)
   endif
endfunction
imap <expr> <CR> F_ind()
```

Note I use `softtabstop=3`, so adjust the `/ 3` as needed, or remove if you
use hard tabs.

Comment: Take a look at formatoptions and maybe indentkeys and the related options there.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I dont see how either of those could replace the function I created

Comment: Not for replacing the function; maybe for understanding whats going on with why indent is being affected ans when.

Answer (score 2):

I think the setting `set smartindent` has the behavior you want.

If you use the following `.vimrc` on `a.js`, then you can see what's happening when you create a new line and press `<cr>` in normal mode while the cursor is over the indentation section of the new line.

I'm using the setting set list to make ends of lines visible (as `$`) and tabs visible (as `^I`).

```
set list
filetype plugin on
filetype indent off
set smartindent
```

With this setting on, no tab is inserted in the first example.

```
let a1 = [$
$
];$
```

In the second example, a line beginning with some indentation characters is moved in a reasonable way

```
let a1 = [$
^I10,$
$
^I20$
];$
```

If you want the leading tab to be preserved in the middle line of the second example, then you can use `I` or [ `^` and then `i` ] to move your cursor to the first non-whitespace character.

If you start with the buffer below as `a.js`

```
let a1 = [$
^Ia1$
^I20$
];
```

And then type the command `3GI<cr>`, then this will be the result.

```
let a1 = [$
^Ia1$
^I$
^I20$
];$
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen in the second example? Can you be more specific? If you use `set list` to show the desired before and after state in the second example, it will be more clear to us how you want the indentation to behave.

Comment: The leading tab will remain if you use `I` to start editing the line or use `^` to navigate to the first whitespace character and then use `i`.

Comment: smartindent will screw with other filetypes heavily. I recommend only setting it for the relevant filetypes.