# How to keep auto-indent after going to a newline

Tags: autoindent

I have `set autoindent` in my `vimrc` at the moment, and it's working how I wanted. However, if I skip over a line that it has auto-indented, the indents are removed after I hit enter or move with the arrow keys.

What I want:

```
(TAB)(TAB)//Some code here
(TAB)(TAB)
(TAB)(TAB)//Some more code here
```

What I get (if I begin from the first line):

```
(TAB)(TAB)//Some code here

(TAB)(TAB)//Some more code here
```

How do I keep the tabs from the line I kept blank for organization? I've tried using `cindent` and `smartindent` but I haven't gotten any good results.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3612/18609

Comment: @filbranden Ah, ok. I hadn't seen that when searching. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Did filbranden's link answer your question or no?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, perfectly! Should this post be removed as it is a duplicate, then?

Comment: No, I'll close it :) glad you got your answer !